# Is there any PHP configuration for passing JSON object to android?

Tags: php, android, json, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I am trying to send JSON object from PHP web service to my android app. Initially for checking if my PHP file returns the JSON value, I typed the url in browser and got correct value as desired. To check my android code, I executed the code using correct host url but got only '[]' as output in logcat. For debugging purpose, I created a free web hosting and database in hosthinger.com. This time the exact same php and android code worked fine, giving me the desired output. List of things we did to ensure there is no mistake:

1. Checked the collation of database in both hostings (utf8_unicode_ci)
2. Both the hosting returned correct value in browser.

Is there any specific PHP configuration for JSON objects?. Or am I missing any header information? **I'm not getting a clue why code is working perfectly in one hosting and not in the other**.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include ('mysqlconnection.php');
$mobile =  $_POST['mobile_number'];
$output = array();
$query="select name,status from content;";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $output[]= array( 'imagename' => $row['name'], 'status' => $row['status'] );
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: check your database connection. your code seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to specify content.type in your php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: I have already tried this.The code given above works perfectly in hosthinger hosting but not in my server.

Answer (score 0):

- You should use an [output buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) with a `application/json` header, instead of just echoing the `json_encode()` output.
- Some servers tend to give errors when you're working with MySQL, check the configurations. And do not use `mysql_*` functions, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or at least [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.
- You should check for possible errors in your code, check your connection, query results etc.,THEN you can generate a JSON to give output.
- Make sure your server's `error_reporting` is set to `0`. Sometimes servers print out warnings, notices and error messages that messes up your output.

Comment: If there is any possibility for errors or warnings, I shouldn't have got the correct JSON value in browser? right?

Comment: There are possibilites for this code to fail, having the correct output on the browser means it hasn't failed yet :) Have you checked your output in developer tools? Maybe the browser doesn't show you everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Chrome's PostMan Extension to view the results of your web service. It also shows output as json parsed.